# Radius of Curvature of a Hyperbola

Tags: calculus

Find the radius of curvature of the curve $x^2 - 4y^2 = 12$ at $(4,1)$.

The given answer is $3.77$.

So I get the first derivative which is 
$$y' = \frac x{4y}$$ and evaluates as $1$.

And the second derivative: $$y'' = \frac{1*x*y'}{4*y^2}$$ which evaluates as $-1$.

and plug them in the radius of curvature formula to get $2.828427...$

Why am I getting something different? I try to check my second derivative... wolfram alpha interprets it as "$\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^2-4 y^2) = 12\right) = $False " What does that mean? Is it possible problem set is wrong?

Also, is there a shortcut for finding the radius of curvature in a hyperbola? ellipse has one, but i can't seem to find one for a hyperbola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second derivative is wrong. You could differentiate $y'=\frac x{4y}$ directly and use the chain rule to get

$$y''=\frac{(4y)(1)-(x)(4y')}{(4y)^2}$$
$$=\frac{4\cdot 1-4(4\cdot 1)}{(4\cdot 1)^2}$$
$$=-\frac 34$$

or you could convert the equation to the equivalent

$$4yy'=x$$
$$4y'y'+4yy''=1$$
$$4\cdot 1\cdot 1+4\cdot 1y''=1$$
$$y''=-\frac 34$$

Answer (score 1):

Your hyperbola is

$$\frac{x^2}{\left(2\sqrt3\right)^2}-\frac{y^2}{\left(\sqrt3\right)^2}=1\implies a=2\sqrt3\;,\;\;b=\sqrt3$$

Its latus rectum's length is

$$\;2\frac{b^2}a=2\frac3{2\sqrt3}=\sqrt3\;$$

so half this length is $\;p=\dfrac{\sqrt3}2\;$

Now, the normal to the hyperbola at $\;(4,1)\;$

$$y-1=f'(4)(x-4)\implies y=x-3$$

which crosses the $\;x$-axis at $\;x=3\;$ , so the length from the given point to this intersection point $\;(3,0)\;$ is

$$n=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt2$$

Finally, the *radius of curvature* at $\;(4,1)\;$ is given by

$$\frac{n^3}{p^2}=\frac{2\sqrt2}{\dfrac34}=\frac{8\sqrt2}3 \sim 3.77$$

If you want to read about how the above is obtained take a peek at [here](http://www2.washjeff.edu/users/MWoltermann/Dorrie/55.pdf)